# Source name in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I`m trying to write a source table from query like

```
coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
 ??? as source_table 
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Does exist function in Postgres that i can insert in source_table field?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(t1.id,t2.id) as id,
  CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN 't2' ELSE 't1' END as source_table,
FROM
  t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```